# Dev site redirecting to live URL

Tags: html, redirect, modx, staging

The IP address for the this dev environment continuously redirects to the live website. My developers are confused, and the client's developers (who set up the dev environment) say that the only work-around they can think of is to change the workstation's host file.

Here's the dev IP address: 208.111.58.205

FTP file structure
Home
 - homepage
  -- files for homepage
 - dev site
  -- files for dev site

This is a ModX environment.

(This is not my area of expertise; posting on behalf of developers.)

Comment: What server? Is it self-hosted or in ModX Cloud? Do you use `mod_rewrite` or any other mean of redirection? Details please!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, holodoc. It's hosted in ModX Revolution 2.2.1 (modx.com). I couldn't tell you how the original developers did the website ie with mod_rewrite. :(